# Не отправляются все файлы

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Вот HTML

```
<form>
    <div id="fileTypes">jpg,png,gif</div>
    <input name="file" class="file_input" id="myfiles" multiple type="file">
    <button type="submit" class="ancSubmit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Вот JavaScript

```
$(".ancSubmit").on("click", function (event) {
      formData.append('file', this_form.find('input[name="file"]#myfiles')[0].files[0]);
      if(this_form.find('input[type="file"][name="file"]').length>0 && window.FileReader) {
        var $file = this_form.find('input[type="file"][name="file"]');
        var files = $file[0].files;
        if(files.length>0) {
          var file = {};
          file['extension'] = files[0].name.split('.').pop();
          file['size'] = parseFloat(parseFloat(files[0].size/1024/1024).toFixed(2));
          var fileTypesStr = $("#fileTypes").text();
          var extensions = fileTypesStr.split(',');
          if(!extensions.includes(file['extension'].toLowerCase())) {                    
            alert('You are trying to upload a file with an invalid extension. Valid values: ' + extensions);
            error = 1;
          }
          if(file['size']>10) {
            alert('You are trying to upload a file larger than 10 MB. Please upload a smaller file.');
            error = 1;
          }
        }
      }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Успех');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Ошибка при отправке');
    }
    });
});
```

Вот PHP

```
<?php
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
    define('MB', 1048576);
    $attachments = array();
    $fileTypesSub = array("jpg","png","gif");
    if(!file_exists(__DIR__.'/uploaded/')) {
        mkdir(__DIR__.'/uploaded/', 0777, true);
    }
    if(isset($_FILES['file']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['file']['size']<=(10*MB)) {
        $upload = array(
            'name' => $_FILES['file']['name'],
            'tmp_name' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
            'extension' => pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
        );
        if(in_array(mb_strtolower($upload['extension'], 'UTF-8'), $fileTypesSub ) ) {
            $file = __DIR__.'/uploaded/'.basename($upload['name']);
            if(is_file($file)) {
                if(@unlink($file)){
                    if(@move_uploaded_file($upload['tmp_name'], $file)) {
                        chmod($file, 0777);
                        $attachments[] = $file;
                    }  
                }
            } else {
                if(@move_uploaded_file($upload['tmp_name'], $file)) {  
                    chmod($file, 0777);
                    $attachments[] = $file;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    wp_mail("123@gmail.com","Theme", "Qwerty", $headers, $attachments);
?>
```

Отправляется только первый файл. Не приходят все файлы на почту. Думаю проблема в JS. Код на WordPress. Как это исправить?

Comment: Сколько файлов отправляется, сколько приходит в пхп, сколько добавляется в письмо?

Comment: Если у input есть id, то зачем Вы постоянно добавляете дополнительные селекторы? Если по вопросу, то Вы сами добавляете только один файл: `formData.append('file', this_form.find('input[name="file"]#myfiles')[0].files[0]);` Может быть так? `formData.append('files', this_form.find('input[name="file"]#myfiles')[0].files);`

Comment: Исправил по вашему. Все равно приходит на почту только один файл

Comment: В письмо добавляется бесконечное количество файлов. Приходит только один